# Created executable for a simple script does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I have a very simple script that cleans data and plots a curve from data I have, the script works fine on its own. However, when I run it as an . exe , the execution stops right after it asks for the filename to be plotted and it closes. I don't understand where the problem stems from.

This is the command I used to create the executable:  pyinstaller --onefile pressure.py
(here pressure.py is my script)

and this is my script:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from io import StringIO
import csv
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None

csv_file = input("Veuillez indiquer le nom du fichier ici:")
#wellName = input("Veuillez indiquer le nom du puits ici:")

#csv_file = 'Pressure1.csv'

# Function to remove BOM and trailing semicolons from each line
def clean_line(line):
    return line.lstrip('\ufeff').rstrip('\n;')

# Read the CSV file into a list of lines
with open(csv_file, 'r', encoding='ISO-8859-1') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

# Clean lines 
lines = lines[10:]
lines = [clean_line(line) for line in lines]

# Combinecleaned lines + parser to read the CSV content
csv_content = '\n'.join(lines)
data2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_content), sep=';', decimal=',')

#custom_header = ['Timestamp', 'Pressure', 'Unit1', 'OUT2', 'Unit2', 'OUT1', 'Unit3']
#data2.columns = custom_header

#Getting rid of unnecessery data
data3 = data2.drop(data2.columns[[2,3,4,5,6]], axis=1, inplace=False)
data3['Marquage temporel'] = pd.to_datetime(data3['Marquage temporel'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')

#droping Timestamp and Date
#data3.drop('Marquage temporel', axis=1, inplace=True)
#data3.drop('Date', axis=1, inplace=True)

# Extract only the time part + calculate time_diff
data3['Marquage temporel'] = data3['Marquage temporel'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
time_diff = pd.to_datetime(data3['Marquage temporel'], format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S").diff()

# Find the index of the first timestamp with a cumulative difference greater than 10 minutes
N_index = (time_diff.cumsum() > pd.Timedelta(minutes=5)).idxmax()
N = N_index + 1  # Adding 1 to include the current timestamp

# Replace 'your_dataframe' with the actual name of your DataFrame
data3['Pression'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
data3['Pression'][0] = 0

graph_name = csv_file.rstrip('.csv')

#Plotting
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))
plt.plot(data3['Marquage temporel'], data3['Pression'], color="black")

# Set x-axis ticks to display only every 10 minutes
plt.xticks(data3['Marquage temporel'].iloc[N-1::N], rotation=45, ha='right')

plt.xlabel('Temps')
plt.ylabel('Pression en bars')
plt.title('Pression en fonction du temps')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig(f"figures/{graph_name}.png", dpi=100)
```

Like I said the execution window closes as soon as it asks for the data filename. I run a scan on my PC as I read that malware can cause this but it doesn't seem to be the issue. I am not sure if it is pyinstaller either. I would be grateful if anyone could help.

Edit: I actually solved a lot of the issues by uninstalling all pythons versions and reinstalling everyting and recreating the venv and the.exe. Now, I can execute the .exe file but it sends me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pressure.py", line 19, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Pressure2.csv'
[22756] Failed to execute script 'pressure' due to unhandled exception!
```

After I indicate my file name (my data files are in the same directory as my script). I added some lines of code to solve this:

```
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
       application_path = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
    else:
       application_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)

    # Use the directory to construct the full file path
    csv_file = input("Veuillez indiquer le nom du fichier ici:")
    csv_file_path = os.path.join(application_path, csv_file)
```

but it still gives the same error.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you give some more info? Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
In order to get help, you will need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @alec_djinn : Hello, thank you for the feedback. I am actually a beginner and I just tried to ask my question in the same way others did, to be honest, I don't know how to make a minimal reproducible example for this issue, even after checking the link you gave. The code is not the problem here as it works fine, it really .exe file that closes as soon as I try to execute it. Thank you again for your advice

Comment: Without knowing more info, it is hard to answer as we can't reproduce the error. Have you tried with other scripts? Do you know if a simple hello-world program works? What are your PyInstaller's configuration options? What is the folder structure? Are you sure you have included all the imports?

Comment: give us a sample of the CSV , at least one line, and is this your whole code ?? if it is then how does it drow .

Comment: @Mohammedalmalki : I added my whole code here. I am not sure how to format the CSV to add it so I added an image that shows the plot. Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: @alec_djinn : thank you again, yes, all of the imports are included (I made an edit to include all of my code and an image of the plot). I tried to make an executable for a single hello-world program and similar to this script, I got: "15229 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully." however the executable doesn't work.                                                For the configuration options of PyInstaller: I have the 6.3.0 and I code with python version: 3.11.4

Comment: If the hello-world program didn't run, the problem isn't in the code. Have you been able to check if you have permission to run the executable you made? Have you tried reinstalling pyinstaller? Anyhow, this is hardly a question for StackOverflow

Comment: @alec_djinn : I m sorry for how I asked my question at first. I have permission to run it and I tried to reinstall PyInstaller. I could run the .exe file for hello-world successfully from the cmd (but still doesn't work by clicking on it), for my script, running it from the cmd and I had this error: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pressure.py", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
[15628] Failed to execute script 'pressure' due to unhandled exception! " I already have pandas installed in my venv in my folder though.

Comment: @ReDK121, please integrate all that info into your question. Try to make it easy for people to help you. In the meantime, perhaps this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29109324/pyinstaller-and-pandas and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65393282/pyinstaller-exe-works-from-terminal-but-not-by-double-clicking-flashing-cons will help.

Comment: @alec_djinn : thank you, I added everything I did since in the post.